# PowerShell time conversion to UTC from a GMT+1 string

Tags: powershell

i use PowerShell for scripting some stuff.
Actual i got a string from a logfile - this one i prepared a timestamp like this example:

```
$timestamp = $timestampDate + " " + $timestampTime
#timestamp: 2020.11.16 06:03:27
```

This timestamp is a GMT+1 timestamp from my timezone but i need it in UTC (wintertime).
So i try:

```
get-date('2020.11.16 06:03:27') -f "yyyy.MM.dd hh:mm:ss z"
2020.11.16 06:03:27 +1

Get-Date('2020.11.16 06:03:27') -Format FileDateTimeUniversal
20201116T0503270000Z
```

Now i try how i could format the result to 2020.11.16 05:03:27 in a easy way without string manipulation (my DB field is without timezone)

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Maybe something like this? (Get-Date('2020.11.16 06:03:27')).addHours((-1 * $(get-date('2020.11.16 06:03:27') -f "zz")))

Comment: Perfect - this is the solution :-).
I see i had to read more about the Get-Date options.
Thanks you and have a nice day.

Comment: as an aside, it is _usually_ a far better idea to convert your _date strings_ to _date objects_ ... and compare those. PoSh understands how to compare datetime objects. [*grin*]